# Taking Screenshot of UIView using UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to make an app with a button that will take a screenshot of the object drawn on the device's screen and save it on the device's photo gallery...

How will i able to do that? any idea?

Comment: do you need to take screenshot of your whole screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple describes a way to do it here : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html

```
- (UIImage*)screenshot 
{
// Create a graphics context with the target size
// On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
// On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Iterate over every window from back to front
for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) 
{
    if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
    {
        // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
        // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        // Center the context around the window's anchor point
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
        // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
        // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                              -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                              -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

        // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
        [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

        // Restore the context
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
}

// Retrieve the screenshot image
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
}
```

And remember `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: This does not work if you have uiviews that have masked layers.

Comment: @Haaakon Sorry, that page cannot be found.link not available

Answer (score 4):

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *screenShotimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenShotimage, nil, nil, nil);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This code will take screen shot of your screen and will save the image in photo gallery